# Installation failed: There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: wordpress

I have tried to install some plugins on WordPress and when I try to download them the message “Installation failed: There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.Learn more about debugging in WordPress. ” keeps displaying. Any ideas on how I can fix this.

note : now i use mamp program on 7.2.14 php version because when i try to use 7.3.7 version the apache server not working.

My site now works however I can’t install any plugins or themes .

Comment: which plugin did you try to install. and which WordPress do you use?
and how you try to upload by FTP or direct installer ?

Comment: I found https://fix-wordpress.com that automatically fixed the problem for me. Seems like it locating the bad plugin and disabled it

Answer (score 0):

Please check your plugins folder in the wp-content directory. Make sure it exists there with proper naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method to resolve the issue is by **deleting the plugins folder**.

1. Access your **cPanel File Manager**
2. Go to the root directory of your site and then **`/wp-content/`**.
3. Delete the **plugins** folder.
4. Go to your **Admin Dashboard**.
5. Go to plugins and try to install the plugin you want to download.

The error should resolve now. If you have any more queries related to this issue or the above method doesn't work for you, then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with SSH, open your cPanel >> cPanel file manager then your WordPress installation directory then open the error_log file, which will give you more information about the error. If you see the error related to the plugin then rename the plugin name (e.g plugin_back). it’s much easier to rename the plugin name. Visit the site and log-in. If the issue still persists then edit your wp-config.php from WordPress’s root folder then turn on debug mode so you can find more details about the issues you are facing. Check the snapshot for enabling the debug mode.

https://prnt.sc/qvuy9q

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Mohammad, thanks for taking the time to help Moulay. When answering a question it is preferable to first explain what and why you are doing something before explaining how, the proposal you have doesn't fix the issue so it isn't an answer but a troubleshooting step, thus should be a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the information @unknowndomain. I will keep that in mind.